# "Приложение не установлено". В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: android, apk, install

Создал новое приложение. Стандартный Hello World. Заливаю файл `app-debug.apk` на телефон. При установке выскакивает сообщение "Приложение не установлено".
 1. Минимальная версия андроид устройства совпадает.
 2. Данного приложения раньше не было на телефоне. Создал, залил файл установки, сразу же ошибка.
Если кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался и решил проблему, просьба откликнуться.

Comment: Пробовали несколько раз? У меня подобное было, когда руками заливал APK и он оказался битым.

Comment: Читайте логи андроида

Comment: @post_zeew да пробовал. Даже пробовал залить несколько файлов от других приложений. Все аналогично. Только из-за этого и создал примитивный Hello World, который тоже не устанавливается.

Comment: @andreymal что я там увижу если я файл .apk заливаю при выключенном Android Studio? Не понимаю.

Comment: Вы на одном телефоне пробуете? Или на нескольких такое поведение?

Comment: Попробуй установить приложение на прямую через android studio подключив телефон через usb. Подключаешь телефон ставишь режим debuge, и нажимаешь кнопку run выбираешь свои телефон и начинается установка отладочной версий приложения. Потом смотришь в консоль, какая ошибка вылетает

Comment: @YaPV как это вообще связано с Android Studio? Во время установки любого apk - хоть из гугл-плея - андроид обязательно пишет что-нибудь в свои логи, вот почитайте их

Comment: Попробуйте в разделе build нажать "build APKs" (или как-то так) и уже его установить

Comment: @ahgpoug огромное спасибо! Ваше решение помогло! Все приложения устанавливаются, как и раньше.

Comment: @post_zeew решение ahgpoug помогло мне. Просто странно. До обновления АС я ставил приложения на телефон, как описал в вопросе и все работало. Видимо что-то изменилось. Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для правильной генерации APK файлов необходимо в разделе "build" выбрать пункт "build APK". Полученный файл можно использовать для установки на любые устройства без режима отладки.

Comment: как? Я собрал билд / апк, сбросил например через Вотсапп и все - не устанавливается со словами "Приложение не установлено", хотя через Андроид Студио напрямую ставится
В чем тут ваше решение, не пойму?

Answer (score 1):

У меня оказалось что установщик пакетов был отключен

Comment: Всегда старайся писать ответ подробнее.